# Member's only pages in wordpress, for users with a related membership

Tags: wordpress, civimember

We have a site Wordpress which offers corporate membership, and this extends by relationship to employees.

The client is having issues where users are booking onto events, after the corporate membership has elapsed.

I've had a quick look at the Wordpress Civi Member plug in, to start creating a member's only section of the site. My main question is:

Can the plug in handle users with related memberships, or does it work best with primary memberships?

And... has anyone got experience of configuring this type of set up? Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of?

Cheers

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CiviCRM WordPress Member Syn](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/)c functions similarly to CiviMember Role sync. It provides UI to add association rule to sync membership type with wp role. There is no special setting available for this plugin to include only primary or secondary member. There is a setting when to remove from role.

Add association Member sync rule in your site for the membership type and based on wp roles design your membership section or forms.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep.

So as long as a user has a membership, that will be picked up and synced!

I guess I'll just put into a test site and see if it meets requirements.